# Regex to get all the values in the html select tag

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to fetch all the **values** associated from a **specific dropdown box**

**Example:**

```html
<select id='countries'>
    <option value='0'>All Categories</option>
    <option value='1'>USA</option>
    <option value='2'>China</option>
    <option selected='selected' value='3'>India</option>
    <option value='4'>Japan</option>
</select>

<select id='Gender'>
    <option value='0'>All Categories</option>
    <option selected='selected' value='1'>Male</option>
    <option value='2'>Female</option>
</select>

<select id='Body_ddlSite'>
    <option value='1'>Select-</option>
    <option value='2'>ECOSPACE</option>
    <option selected='selected' value='3'>MILLENNIUM TOWERS</option>
    <option value='4'>ABMIT-MT</option>
</select>
```

**Note: consider above html as plain string**

**Result Should Be:** **For id='Gender'**

```
0
1
2
```

**OR**

```
All Categories
Male
Female
```

For now I have tried to get all the `<option>` for a specifier `<select>...</select>` block by using this regex:

```regex
(?<=id='Gender'>)((.|\n)*?)(?=</select>)
```

Result of above regex:

```html
<option value='0'>All Categories</option>
<option selected='selected' value='1'>Male</option>
<option value='2'>Female</option>
```

**But now I want to fetch all the value associated with it.**

Comment: You are trying to scrape the RAW Html page, use a Nuget package for the same it is called HtmlAgilityPack instead of doing it with Regex. [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/)

Comment: @KunalMukherjee thanks for your comment, but the problem is, regex is the part of our complete flow, just for this issue we cannot include HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: [`(?:\G(?!\A)|\bid='Gender'>)\s*<option\s[^<]*?value='(?<val>\d+)'>(?<txt>[^<]*)</option>`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cG%28%3f!%5cA%29%7c%5cbid%3d%27Gender%27%3e%29%5cs*%3coption%5cs%5b%5e%3c%5d*%3fvalue%3d%27%28%3f%3cval%3e%5cd%2b%29%27%3e%28%3f%3ctxt%3e%5b%5e%3c%5d*%29%3c%2foption%3e&i=%3cselect+id%3d%27Gender%27%3e%0d%0a++++%3coption+value%3d%270%27%3eAll+Categories%3c%2foption%3e%0d%0a++++%3coption+selected%3d%27selected%27+value%3d%271%27%3eMale%3c%2foption%3e%0d%0a++++%3coption+value%3d%272%27%3eFemale%3c%2foption%3e%0d%0a%3c%2fselect%3e)

Comment: Just because you can use REGEX does not mean it makes sense. With HTML/XML/XAML Code you should use XPATH or DOM.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot, it works like a charm, thanks again, you saved my day :)

Comment: You may either remove the question or answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\bid='Gender'>)\s*<option\s[^<]*?value='(?<val>\‌​d+)'>(?<txt>[^<]*)</‌​option>
```